# Django REST framework where put notification logic

Tags: django-rest-framework

i'm new to DRF, and have a simple question on where to locate some buisness logic.

I have a ModelSerializer, when there is a update request i want to send a push/ email. where should i place that logic.

In the update method or validate method., or another place?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use the [signals provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) - in your case you'd need to listen to a `post_save` signal coming from your particular model and on that function you can then trigger the push/email actions.